# Exporting a graph as a graphml file in an R package using boost graph with plotting capabilities

Tags: r, igraph, rcpp, boost-graph, graphml

I developed a C++ program using boost-graph which stores the output as graphml files.

This uses the compiled part of the boost graph library.

I wanted to include this code in an R package using Rcpp, so I used BH, however the graphml writer is not included in BH. I add that I want to include some easy plotting functionality. The possible solution that I came up with are :

- Write a graphml writer, and interface it with the graph package on bioconductor for plotting.
- Write an interface with igraph (no parser to write)
- Any other solution ?

I think that I will use the second option for commodity purpose, however I wanted to know if somebody encountered this issue/had an input on this question ?

I want to submit this package to bioconductor.

Thanks,
Alexis

Comment: Some Boost components require _linking_ with an actual Boost library whereas BH focusses on those parts that are header-only.

Comment: Thanks, howerver is there any possibility to includes the .graphml parser without requiring the linjking to a boost library which is external to R ? Because I fear that the targeted audience of this package (mainly chemists) won't have the ability to perform the linking.

Comment: Have you considered adding the necessary parts of boost-graph to your package?

Comment: Actually I did not really consider it, I think that this would greatly reduce the portability of the package because I don't have the knowledge to do this correctly. I finnaly used igraph for plotting+exporting.